# Deserialisation Failure on adding/removing field in Java Bean (Spark)

Tags: apache-spark, serialization, deserialization, javabeans

We have Encoded Java bean in Spark application using Encoders.bean(Class<?> beanClass). Later on when we remove/add field from Java bean and try to deserialise, it fails with below exception.

Error happens because of bean changes as class structure has changed between serialisation and deserialisation. Is there any way to add custom serialisation and deserialisation logic for Bean Serialisation.

Note :- Fields addition/removal handlers are well supported with customisation in Kryo Serialisation and Java Serialisation. Need to understand any solution for Bean Serialisation.

```
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x57c2b5]  Unsafe_GetLong+0x55
J 8595  sun.misc.Unsafe.getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (0 bytes) @ 0x000000010ab6843e [0x000000010ab68380+0xbe]
j  org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J+5
j  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData.pointTo(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V+2
j  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeMapData.pointTo(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V+187
j  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.getMap(I)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/UnsafeMapData;+52
j  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.getMap(I)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/MapData;+2
j  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificSafeProjection.MapObjects_0$(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$SpecificSafeProjection;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/ArrayData;+53
j  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificSafeProjection.StaticInvoke_0$(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$SpecificSafeProjection;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;)Ljava/util/Map;+14
j  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificSafeProjection.initializeJavaBean_0_1$(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$SpecificSafeProjection;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;Lorg/example/streaming/StateInfo;)V+2
j  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificSafeProjection.apply(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+74
j  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ObjectOperator$.$anonfun$deserializeRowToObject$1(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/package$Projection;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Expression;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;)Ljava/lang/Object;+2
j  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ObjectOperator$$$Lambda$2600.apply(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+12
```

Trying a scenario to provide custom serialisation/deserialisation logic for Java Beans encoded using Encoders.bean(Class<?> beanClass).